# Google apps script: how to persist data in spreadsheet between different function calls?

Tags: javascript, google-apps, google-sheets, google-apps-script

In a Google spreadsheet using the Script Editor, I do function calls, but I am not quite sure if the best way to store persistant data (data that I will continue to use) is to use global variables (using objects, arrays, strings), or there is a better way to store data.

I don't want to use cells which could be another way.

Another question, is it possible to create (pseudo) classes in this environment? Best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Persistent data can be stored using the Class ScriptProperties:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_scriptproperties.html

All values are stored as a string and will have to be converted back with the likes or parsInt or parseFloat when they are retrieved.

JSON objects can also be stored in this manner.

Comment: use scriptDb for more sophisticated store functionality. scriptProperties is only for storing a few small key/value pairs, which scriptDb allows for a much larger store size plus queries.

Comment: ScriptDB was deprecated on May 15, 2014, and will be turned off on November 20, 2014. To move your data to a different type of database, see the guide to migrating from ScriptDB. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/

Answer (score 23):

Both [`ScriptProperties`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties) and [`ScriptDB`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script-db/) are deprecated.

Instead, you should be using the new class [**`PropertiesService`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) which is split into three sections of narrowing scope:

- **Document** - Gets a property store that all users can access within the current document, if the script is published as an add-on.
- **Script** - Gets a property store that all users can access, but only within this script.
- **User** - Gets a property store that only the current user can access, and only within this script.

Here's an example persisting a user property across calls:

```js
var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function saveValue(lastDate) {
  properties.setProperty('lastCalled', lastDate);
}

function getValue() {
  return properties.getProperty('lastCalled');
}
```

The script execution environment is stateless, so you cannot access local variables from previous runs, but you can store `getScriptProperties()` in a local variable because it will be re-run for each return trip to the server so it can be called in either method.

---

If you need to store something on a more temporary basis, you can use the [`CacheService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/) API

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that every query to retrieve or store values takes a *long* time.  At the very least, I would cache the information in your javascript code as much as possible when it is safe. My scripts always execute all at once, so I don't need to keep global variables as I simply pass the retrieved data arrays around, manipulate them, and finally store them back in one fell swoop.  If I needed persistence across script invocations and I didn't care about dropping intermediate values on close of the webpage, then I'd use globals.  Clearly you have to think about what happens if your script is stopped in the middle and you haven't yet stored the values back to Google.