# Identify header row then store as variable unless a row is added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with a number of Google Sheets, which all have slightly different formats.  They do, however, have common keywords which indicate where the header row begins.  "KEYWORD" could be in any cell within the first 20 rows, but once we identify where the keyword is, we know that that row is the header row.

I then have an onEdit function, which makes changes each time the sheet is edited.  This function will use the header row.  Indexing the entire sheet, searching for "KEYWORD" and then declaring that row # as var headerRow each onEdit causes the sheet to run incredibly slowly.

Is it possible to index the sheet once, find the headerRow, then declare that as a variable.  And *only* update this variable if there is an onEdit action which inserts or deletes a row *above* where the headerRow is?

This would drastically speed up my process, but I am struggling to get the code to work.  Could someone help with some actual code to accomplish this?  Is it possible?

The below code works when the "KEYWORD" is in row 1.  I want to update it to index everything.  Then I want to create the functionality to only re-index if a row is added / deleted *above* the headerRow.

```
  function arrayWork() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var headerRange = sheet.getRange("A1:1").getValues();
  var col_val = headerRange[0].indexOf('KEYWORD');
 
   if (col_val != -1) {
    var rangeKeyword = sheet.getRange(2,col_val+1,sheet.getMaxRows()).getValues();
    var width = lRange.getWidth();
    var height = lRange.getHeight();
    var tlCol = lRange.getColumn();
    var tlRow = lRange.getRow();
   }
  
    for (var r = 0; r < height; r++) {
      for (var c = 0; c < width; c++) {
       
       
         var col_val = rangeKeyword[tlRow - 2][c];
      }}
etc etc
```

Comment: You declare col_val twice and it's not clear what your doing in the script it's not changing anything.  The width of active range is `e.range.columnEnd-e.range.columnStart+1` and the height is `e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1` which is all available from the event object.  You can avoid using a lot of time consuming functions by learning how to use the event object.

Comment: You probably don't want to be using `sheet.getMaxRows()`  I'd guess you want `sheet.getLastRow();` but honestly its hard to tell because you code is not doing anything

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks for the comments and assistance.  This is just a portion of the code, and yes it does not have any actions in this snippet.  I was asking if it is possible to store the headerRow and pull for later onEdit actions.  The key here I believe is the indexof()

Comment: If you can store indexOf  for each sheet then why not just  put them in an object right inside of the function.

Comment: Cause this is going to be an add-on run by many users at once, in all different sheets, of all different formats

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> Is it possible to index the sheet once, find the headerRow, then declare that as a variable. And only update this variable if there is an onEdit action which inserts or deletes a row above where the headerRow is?

No, it's not posible but you could use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties), [Class DeveloperMetadata](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata) or other stuff that works as a permanent store (like a cell in your spreadsheet)

Related

- [Google apps script: how to persist data in spreadsheet between different function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8039568/1595451)